# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'point'

Tags: python, arcpy

When I try to run this code:

```
import arcpy, os
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
def polylineArea(x, y): # this is your function definition
   count=len(xlist)
   area=0
   j=count-1
   for i in range (0, count):
       area+=((x[j]+x[i])*(y[j]-y[i]))
       j=i
   return area*.5

infile=open("C:/KateFiles/Courses/SIE510/ParcelStuff/parcel15.txt", "r")
outputname = "C:/KateFiles/Courses/SIE510/ParcelStuff/P_12/ParcelPolys2.shp"

sr=arcpy.SpatialReference(102683)
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(os.path.dirname(outputname),os.path.basename(outputname),"POLYLINE", spatial_reference=sr)



arcpy.AddField_management(outputname, "ParcelID", "LONG", field_precision=8)
arcpy.AddField_management(outputname, "Map", "TEXT", field_length=4)
arcpy.AddField_management(outputname, "Lot", "TEXT", field_length=4)
arcpy.AddField_management(outputname, "point", "Float", field_precision=10, field_scale=2)
cursor1 = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(outputname,("ParcelID","SHAPE@", "Map","Lot", "point"))

header1 = infile.readline()
print header1 # print this out so you can see what this contains
header2 =header1.split()# split the header parts by white space
parcelID=header2[1]#assign parcel ID
Mapno=header2[2]# assign the Mapno
Lotno=header2[3]# assign the Lotno
xlist=[]
ylist=[]

#poly =[] # A list that will hold each of the Polygon objects
#point=arcpy.point
parray=arcpy.Array()
# Loop over lines and extract variables of interest 
for line in infile: 
   segments=line.split()   
   x=float(segments[0]) # gets x
   y=float(segments[1]) # gets y
   print x, y
   pt=arcpy.point(x, y)
   parray.add(pt)

   xlist.append(x)
   ylist.append(y)

area=polylineArea(x, y) # this is your function call
print area
point=arcpy.polyline(parray) 

row=(parcelID, poly, Mapno, Lotno, point) # these match the fields in your insert cursor specification
cursor1.insertRow(row)
infile.close()
```

I got this Error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Ahmed A. Jasim/Desktop/Q3_Lb8.py", line 45, in <module>
    pt=arcpy.point(xlist, ylist)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'point'
```

Comment: This is the code which I used to create polygon area, and I did do this.But now I want to change this code to create an output polyline with each polyline being a two-point line. I want to add Length which shoould computed from 2 point pairs

Comment: Please edit the question to put in the code (from your above comment) and format the code

Comment: ArcPy is likely to be much more familiar to the [gis.se] Stack Exchange users.

Answer (score 0):

The ArcPy module is case sensitive, so you need to [capitalize those objects](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/classes/point.htm), e.g.

```
pt=arcpy.Point(x, y)
point=arcpy.Polyline(parray)
```